# Rails: The easiest way to differ path parameter from query string parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

Rails router gives us an easy way to define optional path parameters, [like this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-url-params):

```
# config/routes.rb
scope "(:locale)", locale: /ru|de|fr/ do
  resources :books
end
```

Thus we can access `/users` path and get the default locale, or `/ru/books` and get the locale in `params[:locale]`.

But with the same setup we can also call the page `/books?locale=ru` and get the same effect (both path parameters and query string parameters are treated equally and put in the `params` hash). If locale is processed in a global `before_action` as [Rails i18n guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-and-passing-the-locale) suggests we can even set locale for the pages that are not supposed to be localized.

So my question is what is the simplest and cleanest way differ path parameters from query string parameters (with the goal to ignore certain query string parameters)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question:

There is a method `ActionDispatch::Request#query_parameters`. It returns only the parameters set via query string.

There are also method `path_parameters` and `symbolized_path_parameters`. It is obvious they return parameters derived from path (including `controller` and `action`). They can be called on `request` inside a controller action. (They are not documented under `ActionDispatch::Request`, this is why I missed them initially.)

**Rails 5** (edit Jan 9, 2017): As of Rails 5 method `symbolized_path_parameters` was removed. Method `path_parameters` is now documented.